# EF 5.0, PredicateBuilder and LinqKit

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5, predicatebuilder, linqkit

Starting using **LinqKit** from Mr J. Albahari, does anyone know if there might be some **caveats** or things to be aware of with the release of **EF 5.0** ?

Would there be any major changes in EF 5.0 and L2E that would imply using differently (or not to use anymore) the **PredicateBuilder** class and the **AsExpandable()** methods for building dynamic queries ?

Thanks for advices.

Comment: There should be no changes to previous EF releases - it is still based on the same code base. If it works with previous EF releases it should work with EF 5 as well.

Comment: Thanks. So I'll go with LinqKit and PredicateBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

This is old question but was ranked high on searches so, caveats:

- You will at some point have to learn the use of complex System.Linq.Expressions namespace.
- Complex SQL with lot of parameters. I hope the latest changes will help a bit, see the end of readme how to optimize the queries: https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit
- For EF6 the async is now at LinqKit.EntityFramework component.
- You will have to profile your SQL queries: Can your dynamic joins actually take the advantage of using correct indexes of your database.